# im trying to insert a table but it gives error "overfull" how can i fix it

Tags: tables

```
\section{Results 1a - Measurements}
Before and during the lab experiment, the data was collected by all six lab groups.
    \begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Property                                  & Unit             & Test 1 & Test 2 & Test 3 & Test 4 \\ \hline
    Blows (Number of Drops                    & {[}-{]}          & 30     & 17     & 22     & 15     \\ \hline
    Oven Can ID                               & {[}-{]}          & 1      & 2      & 3      & 4      \\ \hline
    Mass of Oven Can                          & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 63.49  & 62.67  & 62.06  & 62.29  \\ \hline
    Mass of Oven Can Lid                      & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 24.84  & 26.09  & 26.33  & 75.79  \\ \hline
    Mass of Oven Can, (Lid,) and Wet Soil     & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 70.85  & 73.43  & 77.52  & 75.79  \\ \hline
    Mass of Oven Can and, (Lid,) and Dry Soil & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 69.45  & 71.19  & 74.25  & 72.91  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Also, You can have a look at [our starter guide]
(http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144 might also be worth having a look at.

Comment: Note that the message you got is a warning and not an error. The table may be a bit too large but if you are happy with the way it looks then you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: Any news? Off-topic, you can't use two different units for mas. I suggest you to use (international standardized) SI units.

Answer (score 2):

Probably one of the following layout suits your needs. The below tables all fit perfertly into the textwidth of a standard `article` class (red lines show the width of the textblock):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Property                                  & Unit             & Test 1 & Test 2 & Test 3 & Test 4 \\ \hline
Blows (Number of Drops                    & {[}-{]}          & 30     & 17     & 22     & 15     \\ \hline
Oven Can ID                               & {[}-{]}          & 1      & 2      & 3      & 4      \\ \hline
Mass of Oven Can                          & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 63.49  & 62.67  & 62.06  & 62.29  \\ \hline
Mass of Oven Can Lid                      & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 24.84  & 26.09  & 26.33  & 75.79  \\ \hline
Mass of Oven Can, (Lid,) and Wet Soil     & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 70.85  & 73.43  & 77.52  & 75.79  \\ \hline
Mass of Oven Can and, (Lid,) and Dry Soil & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 69.45  & 71.19  & 74.25  & 72.91  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xccccc}
\toprule
Property                                  & Unit             & Test 1 & Test 2 & Test 3 & Test 4 \\ \midrule
Blows (Number of Drops                    & --          & 30     & 17     & 22     & 15     \\ 
Oven Can ID                               & --          & 1      & 2      & 3      & 4      \\ 
Mass of Oven Can                          & [g] [lb] & 63.49  & 62.67  & 62.06  & 62.29  \\ 
Mass of Oven Can Lid                      & [g] [lb] & 24.84  & 26.09  & 26.33  & 75.79  \\ 
Mass of Oven Can, (Lid,) and Wet Soil     & [g] [lb] & 70.85  & 73.43  & 77.52  & 75.79  \\ 
Mass of Oven Can and, (Lid,) and Dry Soil & [g] [lb] & 69.45  & 71.19  & 74.25  & 72.91  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
Property                                                      & Test 1 & Test 2 & Test 3 & Test 4 \\ \midrule
Blows (Number of Drops                                        & 30     & 17     & 22     & 15     \\ 
Oven Can ID                                                   & 1      & 2      & 3      & 4      \\ 
Mass of... in [g] [lb]\\
\multicolumn{1}{@{\quad\quad}l}{Oven Can}                     & 63.49  & 62.67  & 62.06  & 62.29  \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\quad\quad}l}{Oven Can Lid}                 & 24.84  & 26.09  & 26.33  & 75.79  \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\quad\quad}l}{Oven Can, (Lid,) and Wet Soil}& 70.85  & 73.43  & 77.52  & 75.79  \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\quad\quad}l}{Oven Can and, (Lid,) and Dry Soil} & 69.45  & 71.19  & 74.25  & 72.91  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```